# how to detect is mobile SSR - reactjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using [mobile-detect](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/the-right-way-to-detect-mobile-breakpoints-in-nextjs-301ccb1976bd) library and this tutorial:

[link](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/the-right-way-to-detect-mobile-breakpoints-in-nextjs-301ccb1976bd)

```
/src/utiles/isMobile.tsx:

import MobileDetect from "mobile-detect";
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from "next";

export const getIsSsrMobile = (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  const md = new MobileDetect(context.req.headers["user-agent"] as string);

  return Boolean(md.mobile());
};



/src/hooks/useIsMobile.js:

import { useContext } from "react";
import { IsSsrMobileContext } from "../contexts/isSsrMobileContext";

export const useIsMobile = () => {
    const isSsrMobile = useContext(IsSsrMobileContext);
  
    return isSsrMobile;
  };


/src/contexts/isSsrMobileContext.js:

import { createContext } from "react";

export const IsSsrMobileContext = createContext(false);


my `_app.tsx`:


import { IsSsrMobileContext } from "./../src/contexts/isSsrMobileContext";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps <{ isSsrMobile: boolean }>): JSX.Element {


  return (
    <IsSsrMobileContext.Provider value={pageProps.isSsrMobile}>
    <Provider store={store}>

        <Component {...pageProps} />
           
    </Provider>
    </IsSsrMobileContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

inside my `pages/index.tsx`:

console.log("useIsMobile",useIsMobile())

It shows `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that you can try without any external libraries. It's not the best solution, but it works well. I'm going to assume you have a global store in your app, and I'll be using [`effector`](https://effector.dev/) for this example, but this can work with whatever store provider you're using, just make sure to execute this code within your store library's context provider. I'll also be using [`@emotion`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emotion/styled), but you could just as easily use any other library like ['styled-components'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) or just plain CSS. I prefer `@emotion`, because it works OOTB.

The idea behind this approach is to first render a component that will, in turn, render a DOM element with a `content` property, which will have a value `desktop` or `mobile`, depending on the result of the media query. Then, you can access the value for `content` via the `ref` that you attach and finally, set the value for `isMobile`.

Wherever you have your entry point, create an `isMobile` store:

```
// PageShell.tsx (this returns `MainLayout` below)
. . .
export const $isMobile = createStore<boolean | null>(null);
export const setIsMobile = createEvent<boolean>();
$isMobile.on(setIsMobile, (_, isMobile) => isMobile);
. . .
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useStore } from 'effector-react';
import IsMobileDeterminator from './IsMobileDeterminator';
import { $isMobile } from '../PageShell';

const MainLayout = React.memo(({ ...props }) => {
    const isMobile = useStore($isMobile);

    if (isMobile === null) {
        return <IsMobileDeterminator />;
    }

    if (isMobile) {
        return <PageShell>{'is mobile'}</PageShell>;
    }

    return <PageShell>{'is desktop'}</PageShell>;
});

export default MainLayout;
```

And your `IsMobileDeterminator` could look like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { setIsMobile } from '../PageShell';

const IsMobileDeterminator = React.memo(() => {
    const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) {
            const isMobile = getComputedStyle(ref.current).content === `"mobile"`;

            setIsMobile(isMobile);
        }
    }, [ref.current]);

    return <IsMobileDeterminatorContainer ref={ref} />;
});

export default IsMobileDeterminator;

const IsMobileDeterminatorContainer = styled.div`
    display: none;
    content: 'desktop';
    
    @media(max-width: 767px) {
        content: 'mobile'
    }
`;
```

Now, you can access the value for `isMobile` at any point in your app with,

```
const isMobile = useStore($isMobile);
```

If you want `IsMobileDeterminator` to listen for `resize`, you can change it up like this,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { setIsMobile } from '../../../../renderer/usePageContext';

const IsMobileDeterminator = React.memo(() => {
    const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const handleGetIsMobile = React.useCallback(() => {
        if (ref.current) {
            const isMobile = getComputedStyle(ref.current).content === `"mobile"`;

            setIsMobile(isMobile);
        }
    }, []);

    const handleResize = React.useCallback(handleGetIsMobile, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) {
            window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
            handleGetIsMobile();
        }

        return () => {
            if (ref.current) {
                window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
            }
        };
    }, [ref.current]);

    return <IsMobileDeterminatorContainer ref={ref} />;
});

export default IsMobileDeterminator;

const IsMobileDeterminatorContainer = styled.div`
    display: none;
    content: 'desktop';
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        content: 'mobile';
    }
`;
```

And change up your entry point:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useStore } from 'effector-react';
import IsMobileDeterminator from './IsMobileDeterminator';
import { $isMobile } from '../PageShell';

const MainLayout = React.memo(({ ...props }) => {
    const isMobile = useStore($isMobile);

    const content = [<IsMobileDeterminator />];

    if (isMobile !== null) {
        content.push(
            isMobile
                ? <PageShell>{'is mobile'}</PageShell>
                : <PageShell>{'is desktop'}</PageShell>
        );
    }

    return <>{content}</>
});

export default MainLayout;
```

I'm using `767px` here as the only breakpoint, but I'm sure you can figure out how to get it to work with other breakpoints if you need to.